# Developer org needs Salesforce Content License

Tags: app-development, contentversion

I'm trying to insert a `ContentVersion` item as follows:

```
string before = 'Testing base 64 encode';
Blob beforeblob = Blob.valueOf(before);
ContentVersion v = new ContentVersion(Title='New Document',VersionData=beforeblob);
insert v;
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION, To create records with origin "C", Salesforce Content must be enabled in your organization and the Salesforce Content feature license must be enabled for your user.
```

I tried this a **Enterprise/Platform Org** and a **Platform Developer Org**

Where do I enable this license for development in my org?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is Salesforce Content Enabled?

App Setup > Customize > Salesforce CRM Content > Settings > Enable Salesforce CRM Content?

If so, does the user that is running this code have Salesforce CRM Content enabled on their user profile?

Screen Shot (cause I've got no rep!!) https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrXhD.png

A good resource for additional documentation is

http://na8.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/salesforce_content_implementation_guide.pdf

Comment: The post [Salesforce.com Content in Developer Edition Org](http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/General-Development/Salesforce-com-Content-in-Developer-Edition-Org/m-p/335815#M60615) suggests setting user permissions after enabling CRM content. Admin Setup > Manage Users > Users > Edit User > Check Salesforce CRM Content User Checkbox

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I had check: `Distribute the licenses to the new and existing users`